# MouseEvent does not work in document class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Yeah, i've seen some topics about similar problem here, but my problem is different. I set up an AIR project in FlashDevelop and wrote this:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite {     
        public function Main():void {
            graphics.beginFill(0)
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
            graphics.endFill()
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onEvt)
        }
        private function onEvt(e:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("yahoo")
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled the project, clicked on black square and nothing happened. nothing. Then i moved all this code to another class, RealMain and added it as child:

```
public function Main():void {
    addChild(new RealMain())
}
```

And it worked. So, why my eventlistener not working if class is a document class? Yes, i can use stage.addEventListener(), but why?

Answer (score 1):

Try using not Sprite's graphics property, but make a Shape, draw on that and addChild() it to your Sprite. I expect a Sprite with zero children behave as a Shape, and shapes themselves cannot listen to events.

```
public class Main extends Sprite {     
    public function Main():void {
        var sh:Shape=new Shape();
        sh.graphics.beginFill(0);
        sh.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        sh.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(sh);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onEvt);
    }
    private function onEvt(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("yahoo");
    }
}
```

Should work this way.

Comment: No, output is still silent. 
But if i use **Sprite** instead of **Shape**, and adding listener to `sh`, it works well.

Comment: check if this.mouseEnabled is true for instance of Main.

Answer (score 1):

addEventListener is function of EventDispatcher class and will need an instance of EventDispatcher to be called.

Main behaves somewhat differently as it is called in static way. For having an instance of Main we have to do some work like below (not very elegant)

```
package {
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        private static var _instance:Main = null;
        public function Main() {
            _instance = this;
        }
        public static function getInstance():Main { return _instance; }
        public static function getStage():Stage { return getInstance().stage; }
    }
}
```

addchild helps in creating a usual class.

Answer (score -1):

The document class has to extend `MovieClip` not `Sprite`

Comment: This seems to be a FlashDevelop standard project, these have their Main derived from Sprite. Using MovieClip as predecessor and not using frames is stupid.

Comment: @Vesper — Yes, this is FD project from «AS3 AIR» template.